# Finding a list of Cunningham chains online

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

A succession of primes such that $p$, $2p+1$, $2(2p+1)+1$, $\ldots$ is called a *Cunningham chain*. There are several sites on the internet that show *Cunningham chain records*, i.e., the smallest prime starting a chain, the longest chain of the first or second kind, and so forth.

However, I am interested in simple *lists* of Cunningham chains that allow to search for a chain of length $l$, containing a certain prime, $\ldots$

I am certain there is some sort of Cunningham chain database somewhere. Can anyone give such a link?

Comment: Many years ago, PrimeFan published this: http://primefan.tripod.com/CunninghamChains.html It's not as sophisticated as what you are suggesting, but it should enable you to create such a database. But please, keep it to yourself, so as to frustrate future men with your same question. Mwahahahaha!

Comment: @TheShortOne Thank you very much! It also contains Mathematica code, which is especially useful. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Mmm... I would have liked exactly 25 points, but now I'd prefer exactly 15... oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All credit goes to user "**The Short One**" for suggesting this link in the comments.

---

The following URL contains various lists of Cunningham chains: [primefan.tripod.com/CunninghamChains.html](http://primefan.tripod.com/CunninghamChains.html):

- Smallest initial term Cunningham Chain of length $n$,
- Cunningham Chains of length more than $3$ with initial term less than $1293330$,
- All Cunningham Chains with initial term less than $104730$.

Moreover, there is the following `Mathematica` code for generating Cunningham chains:

```
Cunningham[x_] := Module[{a}, If[Not[PrimeQ[x]], Return[{}]]; chain = {x}; a = 2x + 1; While[PrimeQ[a], chain = {chain, a}; a = 2a + 1]; a = (x - 1)/2; While[PrimeQ[a], chain = {a, chain}; a = (a - 1)/2]; Flatten[chain]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The smart-aleck answer would be that Sloane's OEIS is the Cunningham chain database. That's a general purpose reference, so it's easy to get sidetracked.

[The Tripod page mentioned in the comments](http://primefan.tripod.com/CunninghamChains.html) allows a search only if the browser you're viewing it on allows it, which I suppose gets taken for granted.

As far as I can tell, that page hasn't been updated in years, except for the ad delivery software. Of course the numbers shouldn't change if they were correct in the first place, but the link to [Sloane's A005602](http://oeis.org/A005602) is broken.

Then I wondered: what might I find on GitHub? There's [a Rust program](https://github.com/mikelodder7/cunningham_chain), [a C program](https://github.com/stubbscroll/CUNNINGHAM), and it turns out Cunningham chains have something to do with Bitcoin mining, I'm so disappointed right now...

And the most recent thing I could find on GitHub is [an HTML page with JavaScript](https://alonso-del-arte.github.io/Cunningham-chain-locator/CunninghamChainLocator.html). It only shows one Cunningham chain at a time, or none if you input a composite number, $-1$, 0, 1 or some non-integer value.

Plus it's very limited by JavaScript, it can really choke on small numbers like 95405042230542329 (small by the frivolous theorem of arithmetic). I suppose an implementation in Java could use `BigInteger`, allowing you to go farther than that.

So in conclusion, the exact thing you're looking for does not actually exist, but the things that do exist get pretty close to what you want.

---

On the last link I gave, I noticed that you can enter negative numbers. It's always refreshing to see people not blindly stuck on the idea that negative numbers can't be prime. Longest chain I've found among negative primes so far is of length 3, "starting" with $-19$.

And it got me to wondering about other domains this could be extended to? For instance, in the Gaussian integers: $2(1 + i) + 1 = 3 + 2i$, norm 13, which is prime, or  $2(2 + i) + 1 = 5 + 2i$, norm 29, which is prime, and $2(5 + 2i) + 1 = 11 + 4i$, norm 137, which is also prime...

Or maybe it makes more sense to use $1 + i$ instead of 2? It doesn't make much difference to use $i$ instead of 1, on account of the symmetry.

Answer (score 2):

I made a program that searches for cunningham chains that we use for cryptography protocols at my work that you can use here: https://github.com/mikelodder7/cunningham_chain

It doesn't search for specific primes but you can modify it to do that as needed. This is my code and does not belong to my work or anyone else.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Mr. Lodder, are you the author of the Rust program Mr. Soupe mentioned in his answer? This might seem like a dumb question, but what is Rust anyway?

Comment: Yes I am the author of the Rust program. Rust is a system programming language similar in performance to C/C++. See https://www.rust-lang.org for more information

Comment: Also, I do not use these Cunningham Chains for Bitcoin at all but with crypto protocols in development with the Hyperledger Indy project at the Linux Foundation. Just thought I would put that out there to dispel the notion they are only used in math prime collections and Bitcoin.